# Google BigQuery billing notification

Tags: google-bigquery

How do I know if I have exceeded my 1TB free tier of analytical queries on Google BQ? I can't seem to find it in the billing pane of the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a manual solution, you can have all your BigQuery logs exported into BigQuery - and then run a query to keep track of the total bytes billed:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(timestamp, MONTH) month
  , ROUND(SUM(protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatistics.totalBilledBytes
             ) / 1000000000, 2) gb_queried
FROM `fh-bigquery.audit.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access_2017*` 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

To set up the logs export and other queries, see: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs